# Android Studioで googleが配布しているmaterial iconを使う方法

Tags: android, android-studio

googleが配布しているアイコンを使いたいと思いました。
しかし、Android Studioにどうやってimportすればよいのか、詰まりました。

[このサイト](https://www.google.com/design/icons/)からダウンロードしてきたものを、どこにどうやって入れて使えばいいのですか？

初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、回答よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

1. アイコンを1つ選びます
2. サイズや色を選び、PNGSでzipとしてダウンロードします
3. zipを展開すると、`android`というフォルダが出てきます(`iOS`や`web`用のもでてきます)
4. `android`フォルダの中に、ピクセル密度毎(`xhdpi`とか)にpngファイルがあるので、面倒ですが1つずつ`res/drawable-ピクセル密度`にAndroidStudioで貼り付けていきます

最近のAndroid Studioだと、プロジェクトテンプレートに`res/drawable-hdpi`などの、drawableフォルダがなかったりするので1つずつ作ってください。。。

Comment: @fkmさん、Android Studioで貼り付けなくても、直接フォルダからフォルダにコピー＆ペーストしちゃってますが、大丈夫みたいです。

Comment: もちろんその方法でも大丈夫ですー

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
フォルダにpngファイルを追加しました。

しかし、レイアウトのxmlファイルから参照すればよいですか？
例えば、'android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ファイル名"'
としても、エラーがでます。
エラー内容：Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/ファイル名

何か他にも設定や記述が必要なんでしょうか？

Comment: `moke.png`をdrawableにいれた場合、xmlでは`@drawable/moke`のように、拡張子は抜きます。

Comment: もちろん拡張子を抜いて記述しましたが、エラーが出ます。
`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_grade_black_24dp"`というのに対して、
`Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ic_grade_black_24dp  Failed to convert @drawable/ic_grade_black_24dp into a drawable`
というエラーが出ます。
android studio左のウィンドウのdrawableを展開できないのも気になってます。直接フォルダを見るとpngファイルは存在するのですが、、、。関係あるのでしょうか？

Comment: 解決しました。
`res/drawable/drawable-ピクセル密度`のようにフォルダに貼り付けてたのが原因でした。
@fkmさん、@hataさん、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

**`(プロジェクトのルート)/app/src/main/res/drawable`**

に置くのが基本です。

デバイスの画面密度（dpi）によって PNG (JPG, GIF) ファイルを使い分ける場合は、さらに、デフォルトの **`drawable`** 以外に、**`drawable-mdpi`**、**`drawable-hdpi`**、**`drawable-xhdpi`**、**`drawable-xxhdpi`**、**`drawable-xxxhdpi`** などを使い分けることもできます。

ダウンロードしたファイルの Android フォルダの下に、それぞれの `drawable-XXX` があると思うので、中の PNG のうち必要なものをプロジェクト側の同じ `drawable-XXX` の中にコピーします。面倒臭くなければ、全部移しておけばいいと思いますが、最低一つだけコピーしておいても、一応 Android の方で自動で拡大縮小してくれるので、とりあえずは使えます。

ちなみに、5.0 (Lollipop; API-21) からはベクターデータのアイコンも使えるので、ベクターのものであれば、特に画面密度毎に PNG ファイルを用意せずとも、デフォルトの `drawable` に一つだけ配置しておけば ok です。SVG から変換して使えるようになります。→[参考サイト](http://watercelldev.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/10/30/164959)